# How to solve the Error of pdf2jpg module?

Tags: python

I want to convert pdf to images.
I am using pdf2jpg Module for this.
But It is giving me Following Error:
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
The path Which I am giving, is correct.
This is my code:

```
import os
from pdf2jpg import pdf2jpg
find=os.getcwd()
i_p=r"find/k.pdf"
o_p=r"find/data"
result = pdf2jpg.convert_pdf2jpg(i_p, o_p, pages="ALL")
```

Comment: Are you trying to open `k.pdf` which is in the current working directory? You could use `i_p=‘k.pdf’` or `i_p=os.path.join(find,’k.pdf’)`. Try printing the `i_p` to check its value.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the input and output paths incorrectly. Assuming your input PDF is in the same directory as your script, following code should work:

```
i_p = os.path.join(find, "k.pdf")
o_p = os.path.join(find, "data")
```

Comment: It do not works. Still the error is same.

Comment: @AbhishekRaut Can you update your question with the full traceback?